# How to change css background color of jquery pop up widget-header

Tags: jquery, css, popup

i used jquery to create a pop up alert,but i dont know how to custom the css of the pop up for example to change the baground color of the widget-header.
Below is the code:

```
 dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
       autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 480,
        modal: true,
```

Comment: Use fiddle to show your complete code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no api to change background for dialog jquery ui you need to use custom css, have a look on the below css code

```
.ui-widget-header {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}
```